# Vertically Align col-md-x content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Need to vertically align the content inside the two col-md-6 cols. I've tried with table-cell hack but its not working in this case. Thanks.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 sub-bloque-texto">
    <h1>text content</h1> <p> text <p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vertically align to what? Baseline?
And what exactly did you try?

Comment: I tried with a class "parent" in the row with display:table and "child" classes to the cols with vertical-align:middle.

By default the text content is on the top of the div. What i need is to vertically center it with fluid height.